# Transit Visa for Abu Dhabi needed? (Thai citizen) 4h wait at airport

Tags: visas, air-travel, transit, transit-visas, uae

I hold a Thai passport. I will be flying from Bangkok to Abu Dhabi then Abu Dhabi to Manchester with a return ticket. I have a 4 hour 30 minute wait at Abu Dhabi for my flight to Manchester. I have a English visa, do I need to get a transit visa for my wait at Abu Dhabi?

Thank you

Comment: You asked the same question before and I answered. What happened to that?

Comment: I want to be 100% clear, I was not certain from your answer. Can you confirm I do not need a visa? Thank you my friend.

Comment: You do not need visa, if you are not leaving the airport. Confirm whether its on the same ticket, or two different ticket?

Comment: It is one booking using etihad, a return flight. https://www.skyscanner.net/transport/flights/bkk/man/190301/190501/?adultsv2=1&childrenv2=&cabinclass=economy&rtn=1&preferdirects=false&outboundaltsenabled=false&inboundaltsenabled=false&qp_prevProvider=ins_month&qp_prevCurrency=GBP&qp_prevPrice=603&priceSourceId=taps-taps&priceTrace=201902092120*I*BKK*MAN*20190301*skyp*49%7C201902092120*I*MAN*BKK*20190501*skyp*SN#details/9970-1903011805--32339-1-13880-1903020640|13880-1905012030--32339-1-9970-1905021825

Comment: @Joe Quinn If you want 100% certainty, have you contacted Etihad direct? Or check here https://www.timaticweb2.com/integration/external?ref=d975cfc59f5c0abd06d16e872198110b&country=/GB

Comment: Thank you for the link. The transit visa is not needed. We are booking with a return flight.